# Multiply vector by transpose of another vector in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have 2 vectors, technically represented as row vectors like: (numpy)

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
```

I want to compute `(a*b^{T})`, so `a` multiplied by `b` transpose, how can this be achieved in python/numpy?

Doing just `a*b` should not yield the right result since they are both horizontal vectors.

Comment: `a` and `b` are 1d arrays, not vectors (horizontal or otherwise).  Show the desired output.  `b` does not have a `transpose`, or rather `np.transpose` does not change it.  Read `np.transpose` docs.

Comment: This is quite a basic operation in numpy. I suggest going through a numpy tutorial if you are going to use it more often.

Comment: What is wrong with `a*b`?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for:

```
a.dot(b)
```

or

```
a@b
```

output:

```
32
```

Comment: Why the `b.transpose()`?

Comment: @hpaulj That was my understanding of problem from _I want to compute `(a*b^{T})`, so `a` multiplied by `b` transpose_

Comment: Why the transpose with `matmul/@` but not with `dot`?

Comment: @hpaulj You are right. It is the same and not necessary there. Just fixed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [345]: a = np.array([1, 2, 3]) 
     ...: b = np.array([4, 5, 6])
```

In `numpy` there are various ways of 'multiplying' two 1d arrays:

Element-wise:

```
In [346]: a * b                                                                                      
Out[346]: array([ 4, 10, 18])
```

Inner or dot product:

```
In [347]: np.dot(a,b)                                                                                
Out[347]: 32
In [348]: a@b                                                                                        
Out[348]: 32
In [349]: np.inner(a,b)                                                                              
Out[349]: 32
In [356]: Out[346].sum()     # or sum of the elementwise products                                                                           
Out[356]: 32
```

Outer product:

```
In [350]: np.outer(a,b)                                                                              
Out[350]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12],
       [12, 15, 18]])
In [351]: a[:,None] * b                                                                              
Out[351]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 8, 10, 12],
       [12, 15, 18]])
```

`np.transpose` swaps existing axes, it does not add any.  Reshaping, or indexing with `np.newaxis/None` does that:

```
In [352]: a[:,None]       #  a.reshape(3,1)                                                                                 
Out[352]: 
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [353]: a * b[:,None]              # transpose of [351]                                                                
Out[353]: 
array([[ 4,  8, 12],
       [ 5, 10, 15],
       [ 6, 12, 18]])
```

Dot/matrix product with a (3,1) `b` produces a (1,) shaped result (contrast that with the scalar in [347]:

```
In [354]: np.dot(a ,b[:,None])                                                                       
Out[354]: array([32])
```

Or dot a (1,3) with a (3,1) to produce a (1,1) result:

```
In [355]: np.dot(a[None,:] ,b[:,None])                                                               
Out[355]: array([[32]])
```